# Jenkins automation report email without any attachment is going to Junk folder of outlook

Tags: email, jenkins, automation, configuration, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins automation report email is going to Junk folder of outlook. Intially the report email was having an attachmnet and it was getting triggered to Junk folder, the issue got resolved when I removed the attachment from the report but again I am fcaing the same issue. Everyday the reports are getting triggered to Junk folder. When I check the build run console output, then it shows below settings at the end of the report.

Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Sending email to: abc@xyz.com dummy@test.com
Finished: UNSTABLE

Is there any issue in the Jenkins configuration? Nothing has been changed from script perspective. As per my knowledge there is no configurational changes in the Jenkins as well. However this is happening quite often, the report which was received in Inbox folder for many days, suddenly starts coming to Junk folder. Not sure of the root cause.